# How to create a custom column in Power Query with conditional summation of another column?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table in Power Query which has 5 columns: Origin Market, Destination Market, Year, Item, and Sales Volume. I would like to create a new column which contains the total sales by destination market and year. I need a formula which searches the Sales Volume column and sums up all the values which match the Destination Market and Year of the given cell and does this for the entire column.

I've tried the below formula, but this gave me the grand total of all sales, not conditional for the two matching criteria.

= List.Sum(
Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each [Production Market] = _[Production Market] and [Year] = _[Year])[Sales Volume]
)

I am very new to this, so any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks!

ETA: The code I most recently tried: `(x)=> List.Sum( Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Production Market] = x[Production Market] and [Year] = x[Year])[Sales Volume] )`

This yielded a column with the word 'Function' in each cell, and then asked me to define a parameter for x.
[Image of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhVf1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the Production Market column if your five columns are [Origin Market, Destination Market, Year, Item, and Sales Volume], but assuming that's a typo you have two ways of doing this:

Add column, custom column, with

```
= (x)=> List.Sum( Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameHere", each [Production Market] = x[Production Market] and [Year] = x[Year])[Sales Volume] )
```

or group and expand

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Production Market", "Year"}, {{"Sales Volume", each List.Sum([Sales Volume]), type number}, {"data", each _, type table [Production Market=text, Destination Market=text, Year=number, Item=text, Sales Volume=number]}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Destination Market", "Item"}, {"Destination Market", "Item"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The reason this method won't work is that I want to preserve the current rows, but also display the total for the given destination market and year. This will remove the granularity I need with the Origin Market and Item.

Comment: You should add your sample data as copiable text and your expected results.

Comment: Edited answer for alternate method

Comment: The result you showed is exactly what I am looking for, but I still can't get either of your formulas to work. In the first one, it asks me enter a parameter for x. I don't understand what to do for that. For the second one, it seems to be referencing the original Excel data, which won't work here because I have already cleaned and manipulated it in Power Query. Is there a way to rewrite "Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}" so that instead of Excel it is referencing the current query? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what you are doing unless you post your code by editing your question.  Seems simple to me to just paste in the first formula as provided, editing it to contain  the prior step name you are using in place of #"PriorStepNameHere"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My goal is exactly what your table does. 

When I enter your first code, I enter it as "(x)=> List.Sum( Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Production Market] = x[Production Market] and [Year] = x[Year])[Sales Volume] )" Which yields me a column of cells containing the word "Function", and when I click on this it asks me to apply a parameter to x. So this is the formula as provided, but with the change to include the prior step name.

As for the second formula, it references the original excel file, which is different than the data in the current query.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what you are doing unless you post your code (copied from home ... advanced editor...) by editing your question. Wouldnt hurt to show sample data as well so I know what the code is working on

Comment: Hi, thank you for your patience. My post has been edited with a screenshot of my data and the code I used in the column "Custom".

Comment: You dont seem to want to paste in your code as requested, so perhaps someone else can help you at this time..

Comment: Hi, I did paste my code where it says "ETA: The code I most recently tried: (x)=> List.Sum( Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Production Market] = x[Production Market] and [Year] = x[Year])[Sales Volume] )"

Is this not what you meant? I am sorry if this is frustrating, I am new to all this.